# Magento extend core admin controller

Tags: magento, controller, extend

First day with Magento.

Trying to extend an admin controller "Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_EditController"
with "SF_Teams_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_EditController"

I've been trying Google examples for 5 hours now, and my brain is bleeding...

Can some one please help with the config.xml code? (means, do it for me)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For general information on adding routes to Adminhtml you can refer to `Mage_Widget` `config.xml`.

You need to do two things to accommodate standard route collection in Magento: 1) add a directory to the list of directories for a module's controller and 2) match the route pattern by naming your controller class and action just as the original is defined.

Necessary config:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <your_dir before="Mage_Adminhtml">SF_Teams_Adminhtml</your_dir>
</ ... >
```

[See the standard router's collectRoutes() method as a reference.](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php)

Then in your controller file at *SF/Teams/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/EditController.php*,
you may or may not extend from the original class and override (determined by what you need from the parent class). If so, you need to include the original class file before the class definition, as the system cannot autoload the original file.

Comment: Thanks Ben.
This part is still confusing:
<your_dir before="Mage_Adminhtml">SF_Teams_Adminhtml</your_dir>

"your_dir"??

Comment: Could I ask you to do the whole xml for my case?

Comment: @user635818 - Aside from an encapsulating `<config>` node (the root node in *all* Magento config files), that is the "whole xml" - just close out the open nodes ;-), and remember to clear the config cache. To test that your config file is being parsed, break the XML with mismatching nodes, and you should see a parse error.

Comment: @user635818 - Follow the link I gave to the Standard router class, and look for the `foreach` that loops over `$routerConfig->args->modules->children()`. Note that Magento compiles ALL config XML into one DOM structure, so your module will be one of several.

Comment: Ah, it seems that the config.xml I was using is not parsed at all.
(took over this project from others)